# Распаковать zip архив на angular js клиенте и получить доступ к содержимому архива

Tags: javascript, angularjs, zip

Всем доброго времени суток. 
У меня есть клиентская часть приложения, написанная на angular js.
Есть сервис который который отправляет http запрос на сервер и получает ответ.В ответе от сервера приходят приходят кракозябры вида:

"PK�XKds3.mondrian.xml��]K�0���C��m�~ہl�N�Z��+4�&��og�W#�����y{��N��l���qH�B�t|yAH2-8T���ߝ����Q�ߞ�/@0���d��mY��↵���6/� ��o=�'�Z2QU�`|B�t�J   �du�x�ҧɛMI�~o�G�A��ݬ��mq֮�N�����s��9��V�E�n��sv�a;Ϙ���s
����|������w��7ߨ......"

я знаю,что в ответе от сервера должен прийти zip архив в файлами.
Вопрос, можно ли преобразовать пришедшие кракозябры в zip архив,после чего распаковать его прямо на клиенте и получить доступ к содержимому?

Comment: А можно поинтересоваться, зачем вам это? Мне это не кажется хорошей идеей

Comment: я тоже не в восторге от того чем я занимаюсь,но у меня нет других вариантов, мне нужно достать данные из xmi файла который лежит в этом архиве

Comment: Посмотрите здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095697/unzipping-files

Comment: Я не могу распаковатьJavaScript

Answer (score 2):

Есть библиотека [`jszip`](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) при помощи нее можно как распаковать скачанный zip файл на клиенте:

```js
fetch('https://stuk.github.io/jszip/test/ref/text.zip')       
  .then(response => response.blob())
  .then(JSZip.loadAsync)                    
  .then(zip => {
    console.log("архив text.zip загружен")
    zip.forEach(entry => console.log("внутри файл", entry))
    return zip.file("Hello.txt").async("string")
  })
  .then(content => console.log("его содержимое", content), console.error);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.2.0/jszip.js"></script>
```

---

как запаковать файлы в архив на клиенте и сохранить пользователю можно посмотреть в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/975774/188366)

Answer (score 0):

В целях безопасности, JavaSctipt в браузере не имеет доступа к файлам машины пользователя.

Вам придется или сохранить полученные данные в массив и самостоятельно реализовать распаковку архива в памяти, или сделать так, чтобы ваш web-сервер отправлял распакованный файл.

Comment: Возможно, Вас заинтересует мой ответ =)