# Полное сохранение страницы со всеми прикреплениями стилями и скриптами

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Когда пользователь сохраняет страницу через Ctrl+S. Она сохраняется в таком виде :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как воспроизвести данное действие? стэк технологий: JavaScript, Java, Selenium

Comment: прислать с сервера готовый html файл для скачивания

Comment: действие требуется воспроизвести со стороны пользователя, а не ui-разработчика

Comment: да в принципе не обязательно слать с сервера, тем более откуда сервер знает о состоянии страницы?

Comment: Клик по кнопке для скачивания файла. Состояние страницы можно отправить на сервер

Comment: @Дмытрык можно но не нужно =) все можно сделать на клиенте

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/906077/178988

Answer (score 1):

Это конечно не полное решение, его нужно доводить до ума, однако я продемонстрирую общий принцип:

```js
function dl() {
  download(document.body.parentNode.outerHTML, document.location.href + '.html');
  [...document.scripts].filter(s => s.src).forEach(s => 
    fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + s.src)
      .then(r => r.text())
      .then(data => download(data, s.src.split('/').pop())))
}

function download(data,name){
  let a = document.createElement("a");
  let blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'text/html'});
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  a.download = name;
  a.click();
}
```

```html
hello<br>
<button onclick="dl()">download</button>
```

В дополнение к этому нужно скачать все остальные ресурсы, это стили картинки и возможно еще что-то что напрямую не включено в `html`.

Также необходимо в `html` привести ссылки в порядок, т.к. пути до их расположения поменяются с точностью до обрезки пути.

P.S. Папку создать не получится, однако есть возможность все [упаковать в один архив](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/975774/188366).