# Генерация файла и скачивание его через JS

Tags: javascript, json, download

Так как я практикуюсь в js и его возможностях, мне потребовалось найти способ сохранения данных в моем приложении.
Я узнал что браузер напрямую не может взаимодействовать с файловой системой и узнал что можно сгенерировать объект на скачивание файла. Проблема в том что я заранее не могу знать что сделает пользователь (то есть вариант с предварительно подготовленным файлом на скачивание не подходит) и поэтому мне нужно средствами js создать файл, записать в него данные и скачать. Не подскажете как это сделать?
Объекта формы у меня нет и файл предпочтительно сохранять в json.

Comment: Как вариант на сервере сделать обработчик который будет принимать ajax-запрос с данными, генерировать файл и отдавать прямую ссылку на скачивание.

Comment: просто подождите чуть чуть https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/08/native-file-system )

Comment: Вот тут первый и второй ответ проясняют ситуацию: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3665115/379949

Comment: проблема в том что я не на сервере делаю приложение а локально (без localhost)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для скачивания файлов в браузере есть специальный механизм - атрибут `download` у тега `a`, вот как его можно задействовать напрямую из js :

```js
let text = JSON.stringify({hello:'example'});
downloadAsFile(text);

function downloadAsFile(data) {
  let a = document.createElement("a");
  let file = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/json'});
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  a.download = "example.txt";
  a.click();
}
```

Вот в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/975774/188366) пример как создать на странице zip архив и потом его скачать.

—-

Если Вашему приложению необходимо работать именно с файлами как с файлами, есть [browserfs](https://github.com/jvilk/BrowserFS), который эмулирует модуль `fs` из nodejs в браузере.

Работает с большим количеством бэкэндов -

- оперативная память
- localstorage
- indexeddb
- fetch/xhr
- dropbox
- ...

Всякие там [emscrpiten](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emscripten) и [isomorphic-git](https://isomorphic-git.org) используют этот модуль для обеспечения работы уже написанного под работу файловой системой кода.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, вам подойдет [localStorage](https://tproger.ru/articles/localstorage/)

```
//Добавляем или изменяем значение:
localStorage.setItem('myKey', 'myValue'); //теперь у вас в localStorage хранится ключ "myKey" cо значением "myValue"

//Выводм его в консоль:
var localValue = localStorage.getItem('myKey');
console.log(localValue); //"myValue"

//удаляем:
localStorage.removeItem("myKey");

//очищаем все хранилище
localStorage.clear()

То же самое, только с квадратными скобками:

localStorage["Ключ"] = "Значение" //установка значения
localStorage["Ключ"] // Получение значения
delete localStorage["Ключ"] // Удаление значения
```